# Incorrectly returning empty file list on Android with Delphi 10

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I want to create a list of log files from my system, but the `GetFiles` function returns empty on Android, even though there are several files in the folder (on Windows works).
I can't identify anything wrong or missing. Does anyone know what might be happening?
NOTE: Tests made on Android 4.4, Delphi 10.2.1, Windows 10

```
var LList: TStringDynArray;
const
  ROOT_FOLDER = 'AAA';
  LOG_FOLDER = 'BBB';
begin
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(
    System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(
      System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, ROOT_FOLDER + '\' + LOG_FOLDER));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(LList)));  // returns zero!!
end;
```

Comment: You can use like this: {$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, MYFIELD));
{$ELSE}
  path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
TPath.Combine(path, MYFIELD));
{$ENDIF}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've used a `\` as the path separator. It's `/` on Android. But don't hardcode it, let `TPath.Combine` do the platform sensitive work for you.

Comment: Thanks but, with '\' no error, but no file found. The `Combine` path is `'/data/data/com.embarcadero.MyProject/files/AAA\\BBB'`(however the log files are created correctly in this folder, using the same path in the creation). With '/' throws the following error: `EDirectoryNotFoundException with message 'The specified path was not found'` and the `Combine` path  `/data/data/com.embarcadero.MyProject/files/AAA/BBB`.

Comment: Looks like that path can't be found. Starting point should be to trust the error messages. I hope you aren't telling me that you think the backslash is correct. Do you really think so.

Comment: No, you're right. I just reported what's going on to see if it indicates something new about the problem. I'm doing other tests ...

Comment: I found the problem and solved using the `Combine` individually. Instead of using one `Combine` for `ROOT_FOLDER + '\' + LOG_FOLDER`, I used two `Combine`: one to add to the path `ROOT_FOLDER` and another to add `LOG_FOLDER`. Now works fine on Windows and Android. Thank you!

Comment: That's precisely what my answer says I think

Comment: If you really don't want to use the nested Combine call (which I recommend) you should anyway always avoid having \ and / separators in your multiplatform code. TPath provides the PathSeparator property which is correctly defined for each platform.

Comment: @Frazz fine until one of the arguments itself has a path separator. `Combine` is the way to go. Ideally Emba would have overloads with arbitrary numbers of arguments, or an open array overload.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I agree... "which I recommend" is using Combine... sorry if it was not very clear.